# Error when closing and opening DB on QT5 using SQlite

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt, qt5

I know this a common error as i have been seeing a lot of questions about it, the issue comes as i have not been able to fix it.

This is the issue, i have this function used to update and center the data of my QTableView on my mainWindow.h header:

```
QStandardItemModel * tableUpdate(){

       QStandardItemModel *modd = new QStandardItemModel();
       QSortFilterProxyModel *proxy1 = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
       QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel();

       model->setTable("Main");
       model->select();
       proxy1->setSourceModel(model);

       for (int z =0; z< proxy1->rowCount(); ++z){
           for (int y =0; y< proxy1->columnCount(); ++y){

               QStandardItem *item= new QStandardItem();
               item->setText(proxy1->index(z,y).data().toString());
               item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
               modd->setItem(z,y,item);
               }
         }
       modd->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,tr("Name"));
       modd->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,tr("Class"));
       modd->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,tr("Unit"));
       modd->setHeaderData(3,Qt::Horizontal,tr("Qty"));
       modd->setHeaderData(4,Qt::Horizontal,tr("Price"));

       return modd;
   }
```

I have functions to open and close my DB, these two:

```
bool coonOpen(){

        db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        db.setDatabaseName("/home/adan/Groostore/MainDB.db");
        db.open();

        return true;
}

   void connClose(){

        QString conexion = db.connectionName();
        db.close();
        db = QSqlDatabase();       
        db.removeDatabase(conexion);
    }
```

So once i need to update my QTableview i do this from different .cpps when required:

```
    MainWindow *mainw = new MainWindow();
    QStandardItemModel *modd = new QStandardItemModel();

    mainw->coonOpen();
    modd = mainw->tableUpdate();
    ui->tableView->setModel(modd);
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1,QHeaderView::Stretch);
    delete modd;
    mainw->connClose();
```

Everything works fine as needed, but this is what i got on the debugg console:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
```

What am i doing wrong? its driving me crazy Dx!
Thanks in advance for the support.

Comment: I see many errors in your code, but I also don't understand why you want to close the connection?

Comment: @eyllanesc if you point all the errors on the code, i will apprecciate it. Should i just let it open and close it once i close the program? in many examples the say its better to open it and close once you finished using it.

Comment: Why is it better to open and close the connection?

Comment: "One possible exception might be if you need to have multiple threads of your application accessing the database at the same time. Then you could either force them to wait and share a single connection object, OR you could try to create new connections for the different threads. I have never actually tried this in SQLite. This is one situation where closing the main connection and opening/closing multiple connections might be better for a desktop app."

I found that answer here, if by any reason in the future i have threads working at the same time, i dont need to change the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the error is that you are using the defaultConnection, instead you must create a temporary connection. Also assuming that MainWindow is a window I do not see logic that has a method that only provides a model since you must create a window that will not be shown to give that data, it is better that this method is a function.

On the other hand I find it unnecessary to use a QStandardItemModel and QSortFilterProxyModel to change the alignment of the text since it is enough to have a customized QStyledItemDelegate.

Finally I see that you try to eliminate the model pointer since it is illogical since in theory you try to destroy the information that the view uses, in addition the model is a QObject so using delete does not delete the model, instead it should be used deleteLater, but even so in Qt you should not handle the memory directly, it is better to leave that job to a parent.

**Update:**

In the case of QSqlTableModel, it is designed to keep the connection open while the model exists, therefore the connection cannot be removed. So if you want to remove the connection then you must use QSqlQueryModel.

**connection.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CONNECTION_H
#define CONNECTION_H

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlTableModel>

static QSqlQueryModel * loadTable(){
    QSqlQueryModel *model;
    {
        QSqlDatabase db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "db_temporal");
        db.setDatabaseName("/home/adan/Groostore/MainDB.db");
        if(!db.open())
            return nullptr;
        QSqlQuery query("select * from Main", db);
        model = new QSqlQueryModel;
        model->setQuery(query);
    }
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("db_temporal");
    return model;
}
#endif // CONNECTION_H
```

**aligncenterdelegate.h**

```cpp
#ifndef ALIGNCENTERDELEGATE_H
#define ALIGNCENTERDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class AlignCenterDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
    using QStyledItemDelegate::QStyledItemDelegate;
protected:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // ALIGNCENTERDELEGATE_H
```

**aligncenterdelegate.cpp**

```cpp
#include "aligncenterdelegate.h"

void AlignCenterDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
    option->displayAlignment = Qt::AlignCenter;
}
```

Now just set the delegate in the constructor:

```cpp
// ...
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new AlignCenterDelegate(this));
// ...
```

And then load the model with the following code:

```cpp
// ...
if(QSqlQueryModel *model = loadTable()){
    if(QAbstractItemModel *previos_model = ui->tableView->model()){
        previos_model->deleteLater();
    }
    model->setParent(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}
// ...
```

Comment: It worked, i am still understanding your code,  but after i did everything, i am facing this issue QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'db_temporal' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.

Comment: It is working perfectly, now i'll spent sometime understading it, thanks for the help, i ll mark it as solved!

Comment: Hello, just another question the loadTable function on connection.H is showing this warning: Warning: Unused function 'loadTable' why could that be if i am using that function in my other cpps? Thanks

Comment: @AdanRH that warning is given by clang that tries to detect errors or bad practices, and it seems that it is not very intelligent since it does not detect that this method is used, obvious that warning.

Comment: @AdanRH that warning is given by clang that tries to detect errors or bad practices, and it seems that it is not very intelligent since it does not detect that this method is used, obvious that warning.

Comment: is there a way to get rid of it? Thanks

Comment: @AdanRH add `#pragma clang diagnostic push`
`#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-function"` before `static QSqlQueryModel * loadTable(){`